# How to handle scene loading event in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know I can inherit from `MonoBehaviour` and add some handler functions to `SceneManager.sceneLoaded`, as described in official document https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html.

My question is, do I need to create an empty GameObject in the scene, and attach a script to that GameObject to do the stuff? Or there is some other better practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is one way to go, yes.

You do **not** necessarily require a `GameObject` for this.

You can also e.g. use [`[RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute-ctor.html) and attach the listener within there and then further process it.

```
public static class SomeClass
{
    [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]
    private static void Init()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    private static void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnSceneLoaded: " + scene.name);
        Debug.Log(mode);
    }
}
```

What is "better" depends a lot on your use case and requirements of course

Answer (score 1):

This is good practice. Create a `SceneManager` empty `GameObject`. Attach a script inheriting from `MonoBehaviour` and handle all scene related actions in there.

Very lucid, straight to the point.

Comment: I'm newbie to Unity. Empty GameObject has little resource or performance impact on scene, am I right?

Comment: As far as I know very little to none, especially if you do not change its transform, which one rarely does for Manager-Objects.